# Estimate of mean and variance of a Gaussian random variable from its error function

Tags: probability-theory, gaussian

Let's say we have a Gaussian random variable X with mean and variance to be m and s, which are unknown. What can be observed is the error function sampled at a few values of $X=x_i$. Let say $\operatorname{erf}(x_1)=e_1, \operatorname{erf}(x_2)=e_2,\cdots .$ Is there a way to estimate the underlying m and s given $(x_i,e_i)$? 
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Do you have a prior for the mean and the variance?

Comment: @joriki Let' say no. The reason I feel this is solvable is that I cant find identical erf function with different $(m,s)$ pair. Observing the tail probability is quite common in reality. So I guess there might have been solutions out there so mean and variance can be estimated.

Comment: To get the proper font and spacing for $\operatorname{erf}$, you can use `\operatorname{erf}`.

Comment: I see, I misread – "sampling" and "estimate" sounded like you wanted to do something probabilistic – so you can actually get the exact values of the error function, and you want to infer the values of the parameters from that? That's certainly possible, though I doubt there's a closed form for it; you'll probably have to do it numerically (but I'm not sure). (By the way, $\operatorname{erf}$ is conventionally the symbol for the error function of the standard normal distribution.)

Comment: For uni-variate Gaussian, the numerical way is to take the inverse of the $\operatorname{erf}$ function and and used them as the RHS of equation arrays. This way we can solve m and s numerically. 

How about let's make this more general:

Let's say we can observe the sums of two $\operatorname{erf}$ functions: $\operatorname{erf}_x(x)$ and $\operatorname{erf}_y(y)$ sampled at different $(x,y)$ pairs, and we want to estimate the underlying mean ($m_x$ and $m_y$) and variance, ($s_x$ and $s_y$) where the underlying two Normal distributions are independent of each other.